# Subset dependent on a value being within a range

Tags: r, subset

I was working with some data in Stata where I encountered a small problem. Since there was no simple way to solve it in Stata (that I could find) I decided to try to solve it with my limited R knowledge. I failed horribly.

What I need to do is to keep observations where the (default_year - 1) is within the range given by year, for each orgnr. In other words: I only want to keep organisations (orgnr) if I have information about them for every year (year) up until their default (default_year). Whether or not I have information after their default is irrelevant.

How would this code look in R?

I tried using the subset function and some logical operators but couldn't make it work.

| orgnr | year | default_year | income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 2004 | 100 |
| 1 | 2001 | 2004 | 105 |
| 1 | 2002 | 2004 | 95 |
| 1 | 2003 | 2004 | 75 |
| 2 | 2004 | 2006 | 14 |
| 2 | 2005 | 2006 | 10 |
| 2 | 2003 | 2006 | 6 |
| 3 | 1999 | 2007 | 54 |
| 3 | 2000 | 2007 | 59 |
| 3 | 1998 | 2007 | 50 |
| 3 | 2001 | 2007 | 64 |
| 3 | 2002 | 2007 | 60 |
| 3 | 2003 | 2007 | 51 |
| 3 | 2004 | 2007 | 45 |
| 3 | 2005 | 2007 | 40 |
| 4 | 2010 | 2004 | 5 |
| 4 | 2011 | 2004 | 7 |
| 5 | 1999 | 2000 | 50 |
| 5 | 1998 | 2000 | 45 |
| 5 | 2000 | 2000 | 55 |
| 5 | 2001 | 2000 | 49 |
| 5 | 2002 | 2000 | 51 |
| 6 | 2009 | 0 | 10 |
| 6 | 2010 | 0 | 12 |

Expected output:

| orgnr | year | default_year | income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 2004 | 100 |
| 1 | 2001 | 2004 | 105 |
| 1 | 2002 | 2004 | 95 |
| 1 | 2003 | 2004 | 75 |
| 2 | 2004 | 2006 | 14 |
| 2 | 2005 | 2006 | 10 |
| 2 | 2003 | 2006 | 6 |
| 5 | 1999 | 2000 | 50 |
| 5 | 1998 | 2000 | 45 |
| 5 | 2000 | 2000 | 55 |
| 5 | 2001 | 2000 | 49 |
| 5 | 2002 | 2000 | 51 |
| 6 | 2009 | 0 | 10 |
| 6 | 2010 | 0 | 12 |

Comment: ```year < default year``` doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, made a typo in the orginal post. I meant: (default_year - 1). I need to have to year before the default year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can `group_by` `orgnr` and `filter` any group in which `default_year` is in the range.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(orgnr) %>%
   filter(any(max(year) >= (default_year-1) & min(year) <= (default_year -1)))


#   orgnr  year default_year income
#   <int> <int>        <int>  <int>
# 1     1  2000         2004    100
# 2     1  2001         2004    105
# 3     1  2002         2004     95
# 4     1  2003         2004     75
# 5     2  2004         2006     14
# 6     2  2005         2006     10
# 7     2  2003         2006      6
# 8     5  1999         2000     50
# 9     5  1998         2000     45
#10     5  2000         2000     55
#11     5  2001         2000     49
#12     5  2002         2000     51
```

**EDIT**

As per the latest edit in the question if the `default_year` has 0 value we can add an additional condition to check that.

```
df %>%
   group_by(orgnr) %>%
   filter(all(default_year == 0) | any(max(year) >= (default_year-1) 
           & min(year) <= (default_year -1)))


#  orgnr  year default_year income
#   <int> <int>        <int>  <int>
# 1     1  2000         2004    100
# 2     1  2001         2004    105
# 3     1  2002         2004     95
# 4     1  2003         2004     75
# 5     2  2004         2006     14
# 6     2  2005         2006     10
# 7     2  2003         2006      6
# 8     5  1999         2000     50
# 9     5  1998         2000     45
#10     5  2000         2000     55
#11     5  2001         2000     49
#12     5  2002         2000     51
#13     6  2009            0     10
#14     6  2010            0     12
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. One last question (for future use): Lets say the default_year value is 0, is it possible to add that we keep the observations if the value is 0.

Comment: @IbrahimPelja sorry, I didn't get your question.

Comment: If the organisation has not defaulted the value in default_year will be 0. This will obviously not match any year value (years only span from 1998-2015 in my dataset). Is it possible to rewrite the code so that it doesnt drop the organisation if default_year = 0

Comment: So if the `default_year` is 0 you want to include all the rows of that organization? If that is the case you can extend the answer to : `df %>%
  group_by(orgnr) %>%
  filter(all(default_year == 0) | any(max(year) >= (default_year-1) & min(year) <= (default_year -1)))
`

Answer (score 0):

`only keep observations where the (default_year - 1) for each orgnr is within the range given by year.` This is not really clear to me.

I assume you either want

a. to keep all rows where `default_year - 1 > year`

or

b. to keep all rows where `default_year - 1 < year`.

For this, you don't need the `subset()` function, just use indexing:

a.

```
df2 <- df[df$default_year - 1 > df$year,]
```

b.

```
df2 <- df[df$default_year - 1 < df$year,]
```

---

Example:

```
df <- read.table(text = "orgnr  year    default_year
1      2000    2004
1      2001    2004
1      2002    2004
1      2003    2004
2      2004    2006
2      2005    2006
2      2003    2006
3      1999    2007
3      2000    2007
3      1998    2007
3      2001    2007
3      2002    2007
3      2003    2007
3      2004    2007
3      2005    2007
4      2010    2004
4      2011    2004
5      1999    2000
5      1998    2000
5      2000    2000
5      2001    2000
5      2002    2000", header = TRUE)

df2 <- df[df$default_year - 1 > df$year,]

> df2
   orgnr year default_year
1      1 2000         2004
2      1 2001         2004
3      1 2002         2004
5      2 2004         2006
7      2 2003         2006
8      3 1999         2007
9      3 2000         2007
10     3 1998         2007
11     3 2001         2007
12     3 2002         2007
13     3 2003         2007
14     3 2004         2007
15     3 2005         2007
19     5 1998         2000

df2 <- df[df$default_year - 1 < df$year,]

> df2
   orgnr year default_year
16     4 2010         2004
17     4 2011         2004
20     5 2000         2000
21     5 2001         2000
22     5 2002         2000
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Added a bit to my question in order to try to make it more clear. The code you used is almost what I was looking for. Only two problems (1) it shouldnt drop any values as long as the default_year - 1 is within the year range and (2) for some reason when I run the code it says that there are zero rows.

Comment: Sorry, it is still not exactly clear to me. If I understand it right, the code should drop all rows for `orgnr` 3 and 4, because for 3 the `year` 2006 is missing and for 4 the `year` 2003 is missing? You say `up until their default`, but from which starting point? Could you write the expected output for your data example by hand into your question, so I can see where you want to end up?

Comment: You understand it correct I believe. Added expected output in my question. Sorry for my incompetence!

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear. See @RonakShah's answer for a great solution.